# Can't access child by id on custom view

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have created a custom rotary know view, which I need to attach a listener to from my fragment.
Accessing all other children in the view by id (or by kotlinx.android.synthetic id) works perfectly.
However, this one is null, and I can't figure out why.
When looking at the fragment's view in debug I see it in mChildren, but it's mKey is -1 while all other views have realisting ids.

An ugly workaround was to find it directly like this:

```
val c = layout.getChildAt(layout.childCount - 1) as RotaryKnobView
c.listener = this
```

but accessing it directly by id - rotaryKnob.listener - doesn't work.
Of course this approach won't work once I update the fragment to include more views.

In the layout's xml it is defined like this.

```
    <geva.oren.android_kotlin_metronome.views.RotaryKnobView
        android:id="@+id/rotaryKnob"
        class="geva.oren.android_kotlin_metronome.views.RotaryKnobView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:initialValue="130"
        app:knobDrawable="@drawable/ic_rotary_knob"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/toneButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toneButton"
        app:maxValue="220"
        app:minValue="40" />
```

Also - if I set an id explicitly it works, not that it's needed this way.
For example:

```
        val knob = layout.getChildAt(layout.childCount - 1) as RotaryKnobView 
        knob.id = 12345

        val rotaryKnob = layout.findViewById<RotaryKnobView>(12345)
        rotaryKnob.listener = this
        setBpmText(rotaryKnob.value)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you correctly, but if you're saying that your `RotaryKnobView` fails to get its ID set from the XML attribute, then that usually happen when you forget to pass the `AttributeSet` in the `super` constructor calls in the subclass.

Comment: Thanks, that was it, of course.